# how to remove error "package ‘forecast.HoltWinters’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)"?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters

I want to run this:

```
> library(forecast)
> rainF8 <- forecast.HoltWinters(rainF, h=8)
> plot.forecast(rainF8)
```

But I get two errors for both `forecast.HoltWinters` and `plot.forecast`.

Comment: Did you read the manual for `forecast` package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)? Also, can you please tell us what error you got?

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic functions `forecast()` and `plot()`. The specific methods are no longer user-visible.